# Estoy intentando hacer una petición post a una api rest externa desde node js ,estoy usando fetch y un usando proxy de salida a internet

Tags: nodejs, rest, fetch

cuando pruebo desde Postman si me trae el token correctamente, pero desde la petición me responde como que funciono la petición pero no me trae el token a demas no entiendo porque si le especifico el  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } porque cuando pregunto el header del response me dice application/xml; charset=utf-8.

````
const ProxyAgent = require('simple-proxy-agent');
const getWindowsProxy = require('@cypress/get-windows-proxy');
const proxy = getWindowsProxy();
const urlDomain = config.get('service.url');
exports.getToken = async () => {
  //const baseToken = config.get('service.baseToken');
  //const aportante = config.get('service.aportante');
  //const aportanteClave = config.get('service.aportanteClave');
  const url = `${urlDomain}/rest/security/GenerarTokenRest`;
  const data = {
    AportanteNombre: config.get('service.aportante'),
    AportanteKey: config.get('service.baseToken'),
    AportanteClave: config.get('service.aportanteClave'),
  };
  const proxySystem = await new ProxyAgent(proxy.httpProxy);
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      url,
      { agent: proxySystem },
      {
        method: 'POST',
        // mode: 'cors',
        body: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        // credentials: 'same-origin',
      }
    );
    console.log(response.ok);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
    //console.log(response.headers.raw());
    console.log(response.headers.get('content-type'));
    if (response.ok) {
      logger.warn('Respuesta de red OK!! y respuesta HTTP OK!!');
      logger.warn(`${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
      const result = await response.json();
      logger.warn(`${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    } else {
      logger.error('Respuesta de red OK pero respuesta HTTP no OK');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}; ```

respuesta que obtengo
 true
 200
 OK
application/xml; charset=utf-8
[2020-11-11T12:46:00.024Z] - warn: Respuesta de red OK!! y respuesta HTTP OK!!
[2020-11-11T12:46:00.024Z] - warn: {"size":0,"timeout":0}
[2020-11-11T12:46:00.024Z] - warn: {"error":{"code":"500","message":"A property with the name 'HttpOperationSelectorData' already exists."}}
````

Comment: para el proxy estoy obteniendo el de la maquina donde esta corriendo node y lo trae correctamente y las config también están ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El header que tenés que especificar para la respuesta es `Accept` no `Content-Type`

`Content-Type` es para el body que envías, no el que recibís.

Tenés que especificar ambos